# Trying to print all combinations of an array but i have no output

Tags: java, arrays, combinations, permutation

I am trying to print all combinations of size r in an array size n, but i don't have output. When i used code coverage tool in eclipse, it shows that:

- My for block that is supposed to print the combination - does not run.
- My for block that replaces index with all possible elements, the body of the loop does not run

I have spent days trying to make this work and i just cant seem to understand why its not working. What am i doing wrong? (This code i wrote from GeeksforGeeks).

```java
/*
* inputArray[] --> input array
* data[] --> Temporary array to store current combination
* start & end --> Starting and ending indexes in inputArray[]
* index --> Current index in data[]
* r --> Size of combination to be printed
-------------------------------------------------------------- */

package gfg;

public class Combination {
    static void combinationUtil(int inputArray[], int data[], int start,
                                int end, int index, int r) {
        //current combination is ready to be printed, print it.
        if (index == r) {
            for (int j = 0; j < r; j++) //BRANCH MISSED
                System.out.print(data[j] + " ");
            System.out.println(" ");
            return;
        }

        // replace index with all possible elements the condition 
        // end-i+1 >= index makes sure that including one element
        // at index will make a combination with remaining elements
        // at remaining positions
        for (int i = start; i <= end && end - i + 1 >= r - index; i++) {
            data[index] = inputArray[i]; //BRANCH MISSED
            combinationUtil(inputArray, data, i + 1, end, index + 1, r);
        }
    }

    // print all combinations of size r in inputArray[] of size n
    static void printCombination(int inputArray[], int n, int r) {
        int data[] = new int[r]; //store combinations one by one
        //Print all combinations using temporary array 'data[]'
        combinationUtil(inputArray, data, n, 0, n - 1, r); 
    }

    // driver code
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        int inputArray[] = {1, 52};
        int r = 3;
        int n = inputArray.length;
        printCombination(inputArray, n, r);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This is the flow of your program's execution:

1. printCombination is called with inputArray, n = 2, and r = 3.
2. In printCombination, an empty array called data of length r (3) is made.
3. combinationUtil is called with inputArray, data, start = 2, end = 0, index = 1, and r  = 3.
4. In combinationUtil, `if(index == r)` is skipped, as index = 1 and r = 3.
5. `for (int i=start; i<=end && end-i+1 >= r-index; i++)` is skipped, as start is 2 and end is 0.
6. combinationUtil returns void to printCombination.
7. printCombination returns void to main.
8. Program ends.

I didn't take the time to check what your program is actually trying to do, but I hope you see why your program isn't printing anything. When you encounter issues like this in the future, I recommend you go through your program like this, using tools like print statement and debuggers to help you.

Comment: i forgot that i had changed: if(index == r) i had only done that when i was debugging, it is supposed to be <=r, (which does not work either).

Comment: Is it still not outputting anything when you do index <= r? Try updating your question with the correct code and problematic output.